# Different ways to test the Pod Disruption Budget in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I want to test the Pod Disruption Budget for my applictaion. One way I see is to use `kubectl drain <node>` command but that is something I do not want to do because of some sharing issue. Are there any other ways to test if `PDB` working as expected ?

Comment: You might consider a local multi-node cluster setup like [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) which would let you manipulate a local, temporary cluster.

Comment: Did @DavidMaze comment help you to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but this is how it works.

The first step is to see if it's there and see what the PDB's selector is. You do this with

```
kubectl describe poddisruptionbudget <name> -n <namespace>
```

This will yield something like this:

```
Name:           some-app
Namespace:      some-namespace
Min available:  1
Selector:       the-selector-of-the-pdb
Status:
    Allowed disruptions:  1
    Current:              2
    Desired:              1
    Total:                2
Events:
...
```

Now the important parts are:

- Allowed Disruptions - the amount of pods that may be evicted at this time.
- Current - the amount of pods that are part of the PDB
- Desired - the amount of pods that should always be there

To see which pods are part of the PDB you can do this:

```
kubectl get pods --selector="<the-selector-of-the-pdb>" -n <namespace>
```

This will show you which pod(s) are monitored.

Finally, if you really want to test evicting pods you might want to take a look at [kubectl-evict](https://github.com/ueokande/kubectl-evict) which is a `kubectl` plugin that allows you to evict specific pods.